# Телеграмм бот по поиску в Excel файле и вывод данных PANDAS

Tags: python, telegram-bot, pandas, excel

вот такой бот взял за основу, чет все время ошибки или пишет "ничего не найдено"

```
    import pandas as pd
from telegram import Update, ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, CallbackContext

# Укажите путь к файлу Excel
excel_file_path = "C:\\phyton\\telegrambot\\store.xlsx"

# Загрузка файла Excel в DataFrame
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path)

# Функция обработки команды /start
def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):

    update.message.reply_text('Привет! Я бот для поиска запчастей и материалов на складе. Введите поисковый запрос.(партийный номер)')

# Функция для поиска данных в указанных столбцах
def search_data(query):
    results = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        # Получение значений из указанных столбцов
        date = row[1]
        name = row[4]
        part_number = row[2]
        serial_number = row[3]
        quantity = row[6]
        location = row[10]
        expiration_date = row[12]

        # Проверка условия поиска
        if query.lower() in str(part_number).lower():

            # Формирование строки с результатом
            result = f"1 Дата принятия на склад: {date}\n" \
                     f"2 Наименование: {name}\n" \
                     f"3 Партийный номер: {part_number}\n" \
                     f"4 Серийный номер: {serial_number}\n" \
                     f"5 Количество: {quantity}\n" \
                     f"6 Локация: {location}\n" \
                     f"7 Конец срока годности: {expiration_date}\n"
            results.append(result)




# Функция обработки сообщения пользователя
def search(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    query = update.message.text
    search_results = search_data(query)

    if search_results:
        for result in search_results:
            update.message.reply_text(result)
    else:
        update.message.reply_text("Ничего не найдено.")

 # Главная функция для запуска бота
def main():

    # Подключение к платформе Telegram с помощью токена бота
    updater = Updater('ну тут бот')

    # Получение диспетчера обновлений для регистрации обработчиков
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    # Регистрация обработчиков команды /start и сообщений от пользователя
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, search))

    # Запуск бота
    updater.start_polling()

    # Остановка бота при нажатии Ctrl+C
    updater.idle()

# Запуск главной функции для работы бота
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

не выводит данные запроса, не знаю что уже делать

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7060/178576)

Comment: def search_data(query):
       ...
       return results